# Retrieve value of long int and float from one byte of memory pointed by char *

Tags: c

What is the output of this program and how ?

```
int main()
{
    char *c;
    float f=59.94;
    long l=94527;

    c=&l;
    printf("%ld\n",*c);

    c=&f;
    printf("%f\n",*c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think is the output and Why ?

Comment: i want to know how computer stores this type of data types value in memory...

Comment: This is a dup of an earlier question that you deleted.  Why are you wasting our time?

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running it? Give us the output, explain what you think it should do and why it confuses you. Then we will help.

Comment: i want to know how the value of %ld gives 112984127 in my computer from one byte in memory which is pointed by char *.

Comment: @RobinRbn Basically, you are giving `printf` a value that has a length of 1 byte but telling it to print 4 bytes. This 1 byte value is put on the stack before calling `printf` and then `printf` reads the adjacent 4 bytes and prints it. You don't know what the other 3 bytes are. Basically you are printing garbage from the stack... This assumes stack based passing of parameters which is not necessarily true any more. Regardless, it is UB and you can end up printing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

What ? That depends on the endian-ness of your processor and whether or not your floats are in IEEE representation.

How ? by the printf.

Why (i guess that is the question you wanted to ask)? Because the float, and the long, have internal representations consisting of more than one byte. By accessing these memory locations via a `char *`, you get the content of one of these bytes, which doesn't mean much.

Comment: The OP has posted this question before, started to colelct close votes and then deleted it.  Now it's trying again to get its homework done, wasting everyone's time.

Comment: i want to know how the value of %ld gives 112984127 in my computer from one byte in memory which is pointed by char *

Comment: If you want to know that, why don't you ask it in your question?

Comment: @RobinRbn That is the crucial part of the question that shows you've already tried to understand the problem. If included, it would prevent further down-votes and possible closing of the question. I've updated it for you but it might take time so you should update it now if you can.